# How do you remove older multiples of PHP installed in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, version, php-7, drupal-8

I am trying to run Drupal 8 on one of my servers, but during the in-browser installation of Drupal it's giving me a different PHP version (7.0.23) than when I run `php -v` on the command line (7.1.12).

When I do a `locate bin/php` I get several locations:

```
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php-config
/usr/bin/php-config7.0
/usr/bin/php7.0
/usr/bin/php7.1
/usr/bin/phpize
/usr/bin/phpize7.0
/usr/sbin/phpdismod
/usr/sbin/phpenmod
/usr/sbin/phpquery
```

When I check the version of each one, I see that the `php7.0` package is set to 7.0.23 and `php7.1` is set to 7.1.12. Bingo.

Now, how can I safely remove the `php7.0` installation while keeping `php7.1` and *not* ruining Apache? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can safely remove the php7.0 installation after you've reconfigured apache to use the 7.1 installation. If you're using mod_php it's a matter of picking the right module for apache, but if you're using FPM you need to permanently stop the 7.0 FPM manager and set the 7.1 FPM manager to autostart and then fiddle with the Apache config (if you're using a socket to connect to FPM from apache then you probably don't need to change the apache config).

Comment: Expanding what apokryfor said, the PHP binary used from the command line can be different from what Apache is configured to use. You need to check your Apache configuration to see if you're using mod_php or php-fpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it, after the very helpful comments from *apokryfos* and *Jeffwa* above:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.1
service apache2 restart
```

And that seemed to work! Thanks all.